# How to overwrite values of HashMap from ArrayList using Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have this code in which I am overwriting values of Map from an ArrayList. 
I want to write this code using Streams and Lambda expression

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(arrayList);
        
        Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());

        int i = 0;
        Iterator<Entry<Integer, Integer>> itr = sortedMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            Entry<Integer, Integer> pair = itr.next();
            pair.setValue(list.get(i));
            ++i;
        }
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the map keys to a list, and then loop through both map keys and sorted list simultaneously using IntStream:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(arrayList);
Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());

List<Integer> mapKeys = new ArrayList<>(sortedMap.keySet());

Map<Integer,Integer> overwrittenMap = 
            IntStream.range(0,mapKeys.size())
                     .boxed()
                     .collect(TreeMap::new, 
                             (map,i) -> map.put(mapKeys.get(i),list.get(i)),
                             Map::putAll);
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing literally the same as your original code, i.e. set the values of the existing `sortedMap` in descending order, can be achieved as

```java
Iterator<Integer> values = arrayList.stream()
        .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder())
        .iterator();

sortedMap.replaceAll((key,value) -> values.next());
```

This assumes that the list and the map have the same size, as you acknowledged in a comment, i.e. it does not check for the end of the `Iterator`.

It’s important that `sortedMap` truly has to be a `SortedMap` or a map implementation maintaining an order in general, which excludes the `HashMap` mentioned in the title of your question. Otherwise, it’s pointless to sort the values of the `arrayList`…

Comment: you are right `sortedMap` is actually a `LinkedHashMap`. My bad that I mentioned hashmap in title. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented in different ways:

1. Convert `keySet` of the sorted map into list and use indexes to build a map using `Collectors.toMap`:

```java
List<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
Map<Integer, Integer> res = IntStream
        .range(0, list.size())
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> keys.get(i), i -> list.get(i), (a, b)-> a, TreeMap::new));
System.out.println(res);
```

2. Use `AtomicInteger` and its `getAndIncrement` when streaming by keys of the sorted map to refer the element in the list with the updates:

```java
AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
Map<Integer, Integer> res2 = map.keySet()
                                .stream()
                                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                    k -> k, 
                                    k -> list.get(i.getAndIncrement()), 
                                    (a, b) -> a, 
                                    TreeMap::new // or LinkedHashMap::new as keys are sorted
                                ));
System.out.println(res2);
```

3. Similarly to previous implementation, current map may be modified using `forEach` of the map's `entrySet()`:

```java
AtomicInteger j = new AtomicInteger(0);
map.entrySet().forEach(e -> e.setValue(list.get(j.getAndIncrement())));
```

Extra safety measures may need to be added, for instance, handling of the case when the map and the list are of different size.

These examples prove the feasibility of such task, though the task itself does not seem to be an appropriate application of Stream API.

Comment: @AlexRundenko map and list are always going to be of the same size in this scenario. I appreciate your help for these examples that are indeed feasible for this task. I am new to streams so trying to get an understanding.